# WooCommerce Product Order Item Meta linked with Bundled products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using Product Add-ons plugin to add extra fields to product "November School Lunches". Custom fields are Child Name, Child Grade and School.

I also have installed Bundled Products plugin to attach other products with "November School Lunches" product.

Below image is from the Orders page after the order has placed successfully. Now you can see Custom fields are only attached to Parent Product (November School Lunches). But I want theses custom fields to attach with the bundles products also.

[image: Here is the image of Order page, which is further linked with bundled products.]

Because in the end I want to export all my orders and custom fields value will be under their custom label. In that image, Custom fields (Child Name/Grade/School) are displaying value of only parent product "November School Lunches" while bundled (child) products are just showing. I want to display custom fields value in front of child products also which are linked to parent product.

[image: Here is the second image which tells you exactly what I want.]

Here I'm using Export Order Items Pro plugin to export orders list.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify your post.

Comment: @Max You need to break your problem into several parts. Also it would be better if you specified precisely and clearly what you want within the text of your question - it is quite difficult to navigate backwards and forwards between this page and your rather messy images.

Comment: @Annabel I have made changes to the question and add some more detail for better understanding :)